# Oscillating a value within range

Tags: c++, time

How can I oscillate within a range, but with a constant time interval? I came up with the next algorithm, but has the problem that increasing the Range makes the result value to also be too fast.

```
const int RANGE = 5; // Oscillate between -5 and 5
long start = 0;

float getStepTime()
{
    struct timespec ts;
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW, &ts);
    long now = ts.tv_sec * 1000 + ts.tv_nsec / 1000000ULL;

    if (start == 0) { start = now; }

    float ellapsed = (now - start) / 1000.0f;
    float result = sin(ellapsed) * RANGE;

    printf("%f", result);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: What do you aim ? Why would you use the clock here ? Do you need to have a period in a specific amount of time for instance ?

Comment: are you talking about calculating something of a physical oscillation? (i see sin function).  trying to get position of something at a time? sorry but i think even you will not understand this question when you read it two weeks later.

Comment: Is simple. To oscillate (ping-pong) a time value within a range such as -5 to 5 seconds or anything larger such as -100 seconds to 100 seconds. By oscillating it means to go forward and back on that range none stop.

Comment: "but has the problem that increasing the Range makes the result value to also be too fast." what does it mean? do you mean the slope(absolute value) of sin function increases? because what I understand from the code is if you set RANGE=PI(3,14...) you will have the exact sin(t-start) (t is timein mseconds.)  Are you trying to scale the sin function with the range while keeping the slope(derivative)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>The usual way to solve this problem is to modify your result line:</strike>

```
float result = sin(elapsed / RANGE) * RANGE;
```

You could also substitute

```
float result = sin(elapsed / MODIFIER) * RANGE;
```

if you need independent control over how quickly/slowly it updates.

If you want the rate-of-change to be constant, then the sin() function is unwarranted. Instead, write:

```
float result = std::abs(std::remainder(elapsed * FACTOR, RANGE*2));
```

Where 'FACTOR' allows you to speed up or slow down the rate at which it ascends and descends.

Comment: This is what I thought but found an issue. Lets say "sin(elapsed / 10) * 10", this seems to work fine at first glance, but as it gets closer to the range limit (-10 or 10) the result is a slowed down value and not in a constant interval.

Comment: are you sure you want to have a `sin(x)` output with regular interval for `x` ? Because this is what you get. What do you mean by slow down ?

Comment: This does that job. Is the perfect solution.

Answer (score 5):

This formula

```
float result = sin(ellapsed) * RANGE;
```

produces an output of constant frequency, the time between zero-crossings is constant.
Assuming you need a constant slope around 0, you can use:

```
float result = sin(ellapsed/RANGE) * RANGE;
```

Comment: then should not you multiply the argument with PI also? I assume that you are trying to span the interval to fit over 10 seconds (-5, 5) periods.

Comment: I didn't add any other factors, because according to the question the output is ok for `RANGE = 5`, but too fast for bigger ranges.